# Risk Faced With Insurance

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying a simple models of insurance.  Suppose that a machine breaks down with probability $p$, and suppose that an insurance company collects enough in premiums to pay for $k$ breakdowns.  What is the probability that there are at least $k$ break downs before yours breaks down?  Note that some number $n$ machines are insured.  Since it is insurance, uninsured machines don't "count".

It's pretty straightforward to put these in a summation form.  If there are $n$ machines getting insured, then the number of machines that break down is binomial (or normal, under CLT approximation), so that the probability that $k'$ machines break down is:

$$
   f(k') = \binom{n}{k'} p^{k'} (1 - p)^{n-k'}
$$

Now, if your machine is one of the $k'$ machines that breaks down, for $k' > k$, there are $(k' - k)!k!$ orders of breakdowns that preserve the condition (of course, I'm assuming each order is equally likely).  So the probability that my machine breaks down after the $k$th machine, given that there are $k'$ breakdowns, is $\binom{k'}{k}^{-1}$.  So using the law of total probability, we get:

$$ \sum_{k'=k}^{k'=n} \binom{n}{k'} \binom{k'}{k}^{-1} p^{k'} (1-p)^{n-k'}  \\
$$

Is there a way to evaluate that sum?

Answer (score 1):

The binomial distribution does not apply under the given statement of the problem.  In fact, there is insufficient information in the problem to determine the desired probability, because the question asks for a probability related to observing one event (at least $k$ failures) *before* observing another event (your machine fails).  Without a probability distribution for the failure time of a machine, it is not possible to answer the question.

To help you see why, think of it this way.  Suppose I have two fair coins, called $C_1$, and $C_2$.  I select one and flip it and observe the result.  I repeat the process, each time, selecting one of the two coins, flipping it, and observing the result.  The probability any coin flip lands heads is always $1/2$--this is your "$p$".  Now suppose I am interested in the probability that $C_1$ lands heads before $C_2$ does.  But I did not tell you **how** I chose the coins.  I did not say I chose them randomly.  I did not say I chose them alternately.  You cannot tell me the answer to the question, because I could have decided to always flip $C_1$, thereby giving me a probability of $1$; or I could have decided to always flip $C_2$, thereby giving me a probability of $0$.

Comment: I don't understand.  I said every order of break-downs is equally likely.  So the probability that my machine breaks down after $k$ of them is not binomial (but I didn't say it was).  We can even assume all the machines break at the same instant -- the question would then be, what is the probability that I get in line fast enough to get paid.

Comment: Your computation implicitly assumes a fixed (but unspecified) total number of machines $n$ but you do not state that in the formulation of your question.  Without a fixed number of machines, to say "every order of break-downs is equally likely" is meaningless.  If you have such an $n$, then you need to clearly state that.

Comment: It's conditional on the number of machines that breaks down.  And I quoted using the law of total probability.

Comment: Your first formula is incorrect.  The binomial coefficient should be $k'$ not $k$.

Comment: This also makes your second formula incorrect.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand the disconnect now.  It was a victim of editing.  Okay, will chug some more and edit.